# how to Styling for printing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core

to print the contract, I want to do some parts of the table in the middle of the line and look like what you see in the picture

I did them correctly in View, but in JavaScript I want them to look like View in print.

If I put text-align: center in the style, the whole form will be centered, which I do not want. Please help

```
<div class="row justify-content-around">
    <b id="d2">   امضاء و اثر انگشت کارگر</b>
   

    <b id="d1">امضاء و مهر کارفرما</b>

</div>

<script>

    function printDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.querySelectorAll('.print-table');
        var htmlToPrint = '' +
            '<style type="text/css">' +
            'table th, table td {' +
            'font-family:vazir;' +
            'border:1px solid #000;' +
            'padding:0.5em;' +
            '}' +
            '</style>';

        divToPrint.forEach((item) => {
            htmlToPrint += item.outerHTML;
        })
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }

</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I can't get your purpose on this case, could you pls show the html code and tell us which kind of style you want? Because you said you `did them correctly in View`, so what's the point you haven't realized?

Comment: I want to put a space between two items, I did it in html, but in JavaScript I could not do it when printing, that is, I apply justify-content-around to my items in JavaScript. I edited the question, please see the code and guide me Thank you very much

Comment: are you stuck in 1990 or is there any reason why you can't use `@media print { /* styles for printing go here */}` to style your Pages for printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my style below:

```
<div style="width:500px;overflow: hidden;" class="row justify-content-around">
            <b style="width: 50%;display: inline-block;float: left;text-align: center;" id="d2">aaaaaaa</b>
            <b style="width: 50%;display: inline-block;float: left;text-align: center;"id="d1">bbbbbbb</b>  
        </div>
```

We need to make  to be `display as inline block`, so that we can set the width attribute for it, here's 50%, but after setting it as inline-block,  will become a block element that it will display each  in one line, so here we need to add `float` attribute so that they will display in one line, then add `overflow hidden` in the parent div. Pls note here, the div need to identify a width and I set 500px for test here.

[image]

Solution 2 is, not a good solution, just append `&nbsp` behind like : `$('#d2').append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");`

Comment: I mean using `&nbsp;` in html will work like we enter space in text box.

Comment: Actually it should be printing as it looks in html if you use <body onload=print();>